# Bitnami Wampstack: PHP caching requires server restart

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, localhost, wamp

I setup a WAMP stack for the first time using [Bitnami](https://bitnami.com/stack/wamp). Got working pretty quickly with vhost and everything, running a couple WordPress websites for local development. The problem is, nearly everytime I save a change to a PHP file the changes don't appear when I refresh the browser unless I restart the Apache server.

I've searched around for a couple days now for a solution but nothing seems to work, considering going back to XAMPP for local development. I tried to disable `opcache` in the php.ini as someone suggested but that didn't work.

Any ideas what it could be?

Answer (score 2):

In httpd.conf comment out:

```
    # Include conf/pagespeed.conf
    # Include conf/pagespeed_libraries.conf
```

In php.ini set:

```
    opcache.enable=0
    opcache.enable_cli=0
```

[Source](https://community.bitnami.com/t/stop-cache-completely/24819)